# Calculate whether two hexahedrons intersects or not

Tags: geometry

Can i easily calculate this programmatically?

I can calculate it easily when the two hexahedrons are **convex**,
but them can be **concave**.

Is there just an only way to calculate intersections of the line segments and half planes?

Comment: I'm not sure this the right place to ask such questions

Comment: Do you mean hexagons rather than hexahedra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you write about "intersections of line segments", I assume that you are asking about hexagons, not hexahedrons:

You should use the same method as for general polygons, so basically check for segment intersections. The naive implementation is O(n*n) but in your case with fixed n=6 this might not even be an issue.

You probably also want to check if one of the hexagons is completely inside the other one. If you already found out that there is no intersection, you just have to check if one point of the polygon is inside the other one. Again, you should use the method for general polygons.

Comment: Isn't the OP asking about hexahedra (3d objects) rather than hexagons (2d objects)?

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Thanks, possibly he mixed the two terms up, just like myself. I modified my answer.